# Embed page source code to website

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed, squarespace

I would like to know how to **embed page source code** to my personal website.

I want to show how many YouTube subscribers, Linkedin Followers, Instagram Followers etc. I have on my personal website (I'm using Squarespace).

If you go on a YouTube page, right click 'View page source' then search for the subscribers. Is there a way of extracting this code so it updates automatically on my website every time I get new subscribers.

It would be great if I could keep them all is the same style like I have on my homepage (I have just manually typed the numbers in for now) under my showreel.

http://www.tierney.tv/

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: Take a look at the respective APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to just "embed" code and just display specific information of an account unless someone has created it as a plugin in the type of website you are using. You would have to create API access and requests. Here is the way to Authorize Requests. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

Here with your Channel ID you can get a snippet to get your subscriber numbers.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets

Answer (score 0):

These widgets should be made and supported by respective companies/sites. They can also be found there with respective links to embed the widgets.

Ex - youtube, facebook, google maps have embed codes provided to embed their videos, posts, maps.